# Ext JS loadData method error

Tags: post, extjs, file-upload, store

I've this Ext JS upload file form and it is performed smoothly, like this :

[image: Succeeded Upload]

This upload file form belongs to a page, say Filling Page, that have a Continue Button to Confirm Page whether the page will be saved or not. In Confirm Page, I have a Cancel Button, which if pressed goes back to Filling Page. Now this is where the problem begins. When I went back, upload form looks like this :

[image: Failed Upload]

I'm using POST to pass the data. When I printed it, the result shows nothing wrong, in array form like this :

```
[{"id":1, "filename":"b.xlsx", "path":"/var/www/.../b.xlsx"}]
```

The code for show data to upload file form :

```
var storeFile = new Ext.data.Store({reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({fields: filelist})})

var jsonFile = '<?php echo $this->file ?>';
storeFile.loadData(jsonFile);
```

So, what did I miss? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is this PHP thing that you wrote into the javascript?

Comment: @Alexander it is an array of data file, passed from controller. The array is printed above..